# How to send email from workflows / process builder to contacts?

Tags: email

Is it possible to send an email from workflows/processes towards external users? It looks like Email Alert only target internal users?

Comment: there is a option to specify 5 email Id. You can use that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to goto your Workflow and Click on Email Alert. Edit the Email alert and put the email address you want to use in "Additional Emails" field. 
[image]

Comment: So from Workflows that's possible, but can one use for example the emails of contacts for that Account?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 You want to send emails to all child contact I don't think thats achievable using WF. You might need Apex for that.